# Logging Module to pass event and logging level

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-logging

Hi I'm wanting to create a logging module that will allow me to set the logging level and pass a messaging to the function. Although this doesn't work, it's my idea and needs some guidance.

```
def log_message(loglevel, message):
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(loglevel.upper())
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.getLevelName, filename="mylog.log",
                    filemode="w", format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
    logging.getLogger(message)


log_message("info", 'this is a test')
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

This implementation may not be thread safe and should not be used for production level as it is just to fix what is not working in your function.

```
import logging
# map logging levels
LEVELS = {"NOTSET":logging.NOTSET,"DEBUG":logging.DEBUG, "INFO":logging.INFO,
          "WARNING":logging.WARNING,"ERROR":logging.ERROR, "CRITICAL":logging.CRITICAL}

handler = logging.FileHandler("mylog.log","a")
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel(LEVELS["DEBUG"])

# your function
def log_message(logLevel, message):
  # log file name
  # map logging level to int values
  logger.log(LEVELS[logLevel.upper()],message)

log_message("info", "asd")
```

Well. it is said that setLevel just specifies minimum threshold to display the log, so it should be fine.

> Logger.setLevel() specifies the lowest-severity log message a logger will handle, where debug is the lowest built-in severity level and critical is the highest built-in severity.

Yet, I will not recommend this for production, as you need better written logging function. Please refer to https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial and https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial for better logging setup.

Comment: Awesome, it doesn't error, but it also doesn't produce any mylog.log file either

Comment: I got this working by putting in the following: But is this correct?
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

Comment: I update the post. In short, it should be fine. Read official docs  for explanation  : https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#basic-logging-tutorial